# how to run Parallel COLT programs

Tags: parallel-processing, colt

How to run parallel colt programs? Can you please give link of a sample Parallel Colt program?

Comment: It might help someone if you explain a bit of background or even give some examples of what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

In this blog post:

http://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/calling-java-code-from-r/

the first example is a very simple, short stand-alone piece of Java code to be linked against Parallel COLT.